# Java.io.IO.Exception; there is not enough space on the disk while running J2ME application

Tags: mobile, java-me, ioexception

I am getting following Error "Java.io.IO.Exception; there is not enough space on the disk" while running my J2ME Application can any body Please tell me what type of the Error is this and why it is coming. This error is coming when I am uploading the data from mobile to the server. I am not understanding where is the error it is at server side or at mobile side.

Comment: There is not enough space on the disk.

Comment: Try deleting your unused .Jar files / Games & then try again.

Comment: Thanks for you response so according to you ppl their is not enough space on my mobile it self and problem is not of the server am I correct OK then i will delete or uninstall some of my JAR files from mobile and tried it out. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: At what particular point you are getting this error ? time of installation or at running time ?

Comment: I am getting error while running my application and we are using 5300 Nokia mobile.

Comment: Found that the drive in which my project was there F:Drive it was almost full so cut - paste my project to another drive on my pc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With respect to your question, as per the given information,

```
Java.io.IOException; there is not enough space on the disk
```

is thrown, say if you try copying something to a destination drive, if the drive is full, you get the exception. The `Java.io.IOException`  exceptions produced by failed or interrupted I/O operations, in this case an interupted IO operation and the reason is `there is not enough space on the disk` , I think its pretty clear from the message.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay for sharing in future I will take care of this.