# Which exception is thrown when phone memory is filled?

Tags: java, android, exception

I am trying to create some files programmatically in Android, which are to be saved in the *phone's internal* memory. My question is , which **exception** am I supposed to catch in the event that the phone memory completely fills up *as* I create and save the files?

Essentially, I want to know which exception is triggered, so that I can prevent my app from crashing in that event.

**EDIT:** I came to know that **IOException** is triggered. But how do I track whether this exception occured, *because* internal memory was full? Since IOException can occur for variety of reasons, how do I **track** this particular scenario?

Comment: It will probably be an IOException with a specific message saying not enough free space or something. Why not writing a small app that simulates it?

Comment: Because the event of this actually happening is not that common, I wanted to know what exactly is thrown in such a scenario, instead of simulating it.

Comment: Don't you just need to write an app that fills the phone with files and check the exception?
Anyway, maybe this will help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046540/java-io-io-exception-there-is-not-enough-space-on-the-disk-while-running-j2me-a

Comment: Ok but since IOexception corresponds to a broad array of exceptions, how do I catch this exception in particular? That is, how do I get to know **programmatically** that app crashed because memory was full?

Comment: Edited my question accordingly

Comment: Even though I don't like it, parsing the exception message is something you can do.

Comment: Yes I guess I should try that, how exactly to do that? Could you please let me know?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [OutOfMemoryError](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)? . according to the doc

> Thrown when a request for memory is made that can not be satisfied using the available platform resources. Such a request may be made by both the running application or by an internal function of the VM.

Comment: That's what I thought.But then I got the doubt that this was for the **heap** memory pertaining to the app. What about for the **phone's internal** memory?

Comment: I don't think he's talking about memory; he's talking about saving files.

Comment: oh ,, i misunderstood too .. .. then how about getting the available amount of free memory first ?

Comment: @StinePike: Could you please shed some light as to how to do that for *phone's internal memory* in Android? :)

Comment: check this so thread.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133417/android-get-free-size-of-internal-external-memory ... i meant something like this

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the one you're looking for

```
    try{

       }catch(java.lang.OutOfMemoryError e)   {
               Log.v("Exceptional exception", e.getMessage());
```

Comment: That's what I thought.But then I got the doubt that this was for the heap memory pertaining to the app. What about for the phone's internal memory?

Answer (score 0):

```
OOM. i.e out of memory exception
```

Comment: That's what I thought.But then I got the doubt that this was for the heap memory pertaining to the app. What about for the phone's internal memory?

Comment: @Pankaj, please care to improve on this answer, as it does not meet the [standards](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) of StackOverflow's answer formats. Thanks